# How to use full path to controllers in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I set project path in `/config/app.php` like as:

```
http://localhost/project/public/
```

So, when I call any controller clicking by link:

```
<a href="/users">Users</a>
```

This calls controller `users`.

As you see `href` is absolute.

How I can set link for each links with full path project, like as:

```
http://localhost/project/public/users
```

Comment: `<a href="{{ url('users') }}">`

Comment: Write this as answer, it is solution, thanks

Comment: @Putin have you even bothered to read the docs? You have a slew of very basic questions regarding Laravel opened. Questions so simple that the docs cover **ALL** of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Laravel's helpers for this.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers

The `url`, `route`, and `action` helpers all do this (in slightly different ways).

```
<a href="{{ url('users') }}">Users</a>
```

<sup>Side-note: Your non-public folders should never be exposed to the public internet in production. Your webserver should be pointed to the `public` folder as its document root.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use named routes, with that routes will work dynamically unlike `url('path')` where you have to change path manually everywhere.

```
Route::get('user/profile', [
    'as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
]);
```

You can access full path with this helper method

`route('profile')`

This also works works for dynamic routes like

```
Route::get('profile/{id}', [
    'as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile'
]);
```

Pass `$id` or any array as second parameter.

```
route('profile', $id)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes